# Closed form for the inverse of $f(x) = x \log x$ over $[1, \infty]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider
$$f(x) = x \log x$$
over $[1, \infty]$. The derivative is $1 + \log x$, which is positive, so the function is strictly increasing, hence an invertible map from $[1, \infty)$ to $[0, \infty)$ exists. But I'm having a hard time finding a way to express $f^{-1}$ (maybe there is no closed form?)

Comment: Writing it as $x^x = e^{f(x)}$, I'd be surprised is there was a closed form for the inverse.

Comment: Please see the [Lambert $W$-function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: Yes there is an expression in terms of Lambert W functions. Whether or not this is a closed form can be debated, however, depending on your application. See here: <http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D+x*log%28x%29+solve+for+x>

Comment: What's so special about the function $x^x = e^{f(x)}$? Can you give me some heuristics behind the intuition that this doesn't have a closed form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Maybe there is no closed form?**

Yes. At least not in terms of elementary functions. However, you can express it in terms of certain special functions, such as [Lambert's *W* function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), in a way similar to that described in ‘Example $2$’.

> **An invertible map from $[1,\infty)$  to $[0,\infty)$  exists.**

Just because something exists, doesn't mean that it can also be expressed in terms of other things. Fundamental colors also exist, but they cannot be expressed as a combination of other colors.

> **Can you give me some heuristics behind the intuition that this doesn't have a closed form ?**

As far as “heuristics” and “intuition” are concerned, try comparing this situation with that of anti-derivatives; i.e., just because a function can be expressed as a combination of elementary functions does not mean that its primitive has the same property. Take, for instance, $e^{-x^2}$, whose integral is the non-elementary [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). But in order to actually be able to prove these facts, knowledge of [abstract algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) is required.